# UIScrollView - transparent PNG sliding over an image background

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

Trying to get PNG transparency to appear in a UIScrollView. Instead of transparent is all black now. I tried to set view.opaque = NO, and view.backGroundcolor = [UIColor clearColor] to no avail.

RootViewController has an image background set with

```
self.view.opaque = NO;    
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"appBackground.png"]];
```

RootViewController has also a UIScrollView that I load other two UIViewController views (leftScreen, centralScreen) into:

```
CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;  
frame.origin.y = 0;
leftScreen.view.frame = frame;
[scrollView addSubview:leftScreen.view];

frame.origin.x = frame.size.width;
frame.origin.y = 0;
centralScreen.view.frame = frame;
[scrollView addSubview:centralScreen.view];
```

The centralScreen.view has a 24bit transparent PNG background that I set in its UIViewController with

```
self.view.opaque = NO;    
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"homePageText.png"]];
```

In the end the centralScreen background PNG has black where the transparency should be. Any recommendations/hints on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, what do you expect to see behind the transparency? Are you trying to get the central screen to slide over the left screen? It looks like they will both slide left together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use backgroundColor for that, 'cause you lost any control on how the image is draw (i.e.: you can't resize it).
I suggest you to put an UIImageView as "background" (add it then use sendSubviewToBack:).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Using UIImageView to display the transparent PNG worked. Turns out the colorWithPatternImage does not respect the PNG transparency for some reason.